# SSDT project not loading in visual studio 2012 for azure v12 database

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, azure, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

SSDT project not loading in visual studio 2012 for azure v12 database schema provider.

I googled the issue and found that following link would resolve the issue.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-database-tooling-preview-release-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

But, the update as per above link would work only on visual studio 2013 version.

The actual error shown on trying to load SSDT project in vs 2012 is as follows:
Internal error: The database platform service with type microsoft.data.tools.schema.sql.sqlAzurev12DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide full type name of a valid database platform service.

SQL Server Version: 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full release supporting Azure SQL DB v12 for both VS2012 and VS2013 is now available. The blog post announcing this is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/03/03/sql-server-data-tools-and-data-tier-application-framework-update-for-february-2015.aspx). The download page for VS2012 is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015).

Comment: Kevin, Installing the SSDT as per the link for VS 2012 will resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I tried to install using SSDT 2012, but failed as it was unable to download the pre-requisite msi's. Not sure why??

Comment: These were the steps performed to resolve the issue.
1. Install VS 2013.
2. Install SQL Server 2014.
3. Install SSDT 2012 (if not already installed) and then installed SSDT 2013.